# Can contrapositive proved using truth table

Tags: logic

"If P => Q is true, then contrapositive of P => Q is also true". Can this be proved using truth table ?

Truth table of P => Q is

P Q  P=>Q
T T  T
T F  F
F T  T
F F  T

Will this match with the truth table of contrapositive of P => Q

Converse of P => Q is Q => P, and its truth table is

Q P  Q=>P
 
T T  T
T F  F
F T  T
F F  T

Contrapositive of P => Q is inverse of (converse of  P => Q)

so inverse of above truth table is 
~Q ~P ~Q=>~P
F  F   F
F  T   T
T  F   F
T  T   F

The truth table 1 (P=>Q) is not matching with truth table 3 (~Q=>~P)

Comment: Have you tried just writing out the truth table for the contrapositive?

Comment: Yes I tried. First I did truth table for converse and then truth table for inverse of converse, which is contrapositive.

Comment: Please see my answer below. The tables are not match visually, but when you check each case individually, the result matches. let me know if you need further explaination

Comment: Hi Bongers, I have updated my question with the truth table for contrapositive, please let me know your thoughts

Comment: @Karthik: The equivalence is clear (and easy to establish) if you make _one_ table whose columns contain truth values for $P$, $Q$, $P \implies Q$, $\neg Q$, $\neg P$, and $\neg Q \implies \neg P$. (Incidentally, the third column of your inverse table is, as stated, not OK.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, thanks. Please kindly let me know inverse of Q=>P truth table.

Comment: @T.Bongers, when I write truth table for contrapositive its matching. But when I write a truth table for Q=>P and then a truth table for its inverse, this inverse truth table is not matching with P=>Q. Please clarify why ?

Comment: @Karthik: In your column for $\neg Q\implies\neg P$, it appears you've negated each entry in the column for $Q\implies P$, but the statements $\neg Q\implies\neg P$ and $\neg(Q\implies P)$ are not equivalent.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, thanks for clarifying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the prove that ~Q => ~P with a truth table. Just write that truth table down, and you'll get:

```
~Q ~P ~Q => ~P
T T T
T F F
F T T
F F T
```

Now check in which cases P => Q is true, and make sure that in the same case ~Q => ~P is also true.

Example: in P=>Q, when both of them are T, the claim is T, as for the contrapositive, it means that both ~P and ~Q are F, and according to the trush table, F F means T, so it's ok. Just do it for the rest.

Comment: hi, I have edited my question to add how I got truth table of ~Q=>~P. Its not matching with your truth table. Please let me know your thoughts

Comment: Sorry, but your truth table number 3 is wrong. look at mine and think it over

Comment: hi, I negated the truth table 2 to get truth table 3. Please kindly let me know if negation is wrong.

Comment: mistakes in table 3: first row - don't forget that in if..then.. claim (a=>b), when the a part is false, the entire claim is true. last row - when ~q and ~p are true, the claim ~q=>~p is true, it applies directly. when fixing that, your table matches mine.

Comment: @Karthik Did you manage?

Comment: In the sentence after the blue box, you likely mean to have "in the same case $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$" rather than what's there.

Comment: correct! thanks

Comment: @user1067083, thanks. I understand the truth table 3 changes as you said when I apply the implies rule and it will match with truth table 1. But when I apply negation of Q=>P, and create a truth table, why doesn't it match with P=>Q ? Please kindly clarify

Comment: @Karthik because when you do a negation you only neglate the Q and P, not the implies. The implies should be re-calculated according to the new values of Q and P

Comment: @user1067083, thanks for clarifying it

Comment: Most welcome @Karthik :)